# Fragment data lost after revert back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

While working on an app, I am unable to resolve one issue. On one of the fragment, I have setup table layout and view pager to cast categories and destination fragment over it. On opening the app, the categories and destination fragment successfully visible on the screen, but when I slide to a different fragmen[while sliding bottom navigationview, and reverting to home , data is lost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPUTY.png)t and then revert back., the categories and destination fragment are not visible. I have attached photos for better understanding of my doubt.

Comment: Are you using a `ViewPager`, or are you just committing the different fragments as you interact with the `BottomNagivationView`? Also, please share your code on how the problematic fragment looks like.

Comment: Have you tried saving the state using Bundle savedInstanceState and calling it after you move back to the fragment ? Please look into the following [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/sending-a-value-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment)